# Interrupt Plotting cycle in Matplotlib pressing a key

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am plotting some figures one after each other (closing the windows, to see the next one), but i need a way to interrupt the cycle and finish the script by pressing a key ("Esc" for example).

I try using mscrt.getch(), but doesn't work, any advice would be appreciated.

The core cycle is something like this:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(ID_SECTION):
    FIG = plt.figure(
            num=ID_SECTION[i],
            figsize=(10, 7.5),
            facecolor='w'
        )
    curve = FIG.add_subplot(
            1, 2, 1,
            adjustable='box',
            aspect='equal'
        )
    curve.scatter(x, y)
    plt.show()
    plt.close('all')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind pressing 'enter' each loop to tell the loop to continue, you could add something like this to the end of your loop:

```
r = input("Continue [y]/n?")
if r == 'n':
    break
```

Otherwise, I think you'd have to add a [keypress callback](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/keypress_demo.html) to your figures. Working from that example, something like this might work:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

run = True

def press(event):
    global run
    if event.key == 'escape':
        run = False
```

Then add this to your loop:

```
FIG.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', press)
if not run:
    break
```

Though, I'm not sure that adding a callback to a loop that creates figures is a good idea. It's probably better to create one figure and add the callback to that, then add a pause or something so that you can see what the figure creates each loop. But, if you're going to do that, the first `input` solution is probably better anyway.

Also note that I've used a `global` in the latter solution, which is [generally frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad/485020#485020).